# Jenkins and Templates for Jenkins Jobs for PHP Projects

Tags: php, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm trying to setup [Jenkins](http://jenkins-php.org/) and the PHP Templates to build and test a simple project. My repository currently looks like this:

```
/source 
index.php

/tests 
index.test.php

/build
build.xml
```

Is it correct to create a /build folder and build.xml insider the repository? do I need to check in any additional files to get the build to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to include the build.xml file in your repository. You should make sure your publication process (I assume you have one) doesn't throw it in production though. You would need an `bootstrap` for your tests too - I would place this inside your tests directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what's the role of the boostrap?

Comment: The bootstrap usually contains an autoloader able to load the required classes that are being tested, and might have some config variables too. Note that anything I say is subject to my own experience and implementation.

Comment: Would the boostrap typically live inside of /builds or /tests?

Comment: I would place it inside tests.

Comment: PHPUnit executes `bootstrap.php` before running any of the tests, and before that it loads `phpunit.xml`. Both of these files can be specified on the command-line that starts PHPUnit if you need to use different names or locations, and they can be changed in your `build.xml` as well.